# Android: vertical space around text with custom typeface

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-font, typeface

I downloaded some fonts from the Noto font family, put them in the assets folder, and loaded them into a `Typeface` object, and then I programmatically set the typeface on a `TextView`, but when I do that there's some extra vertical padding above and below the text. It's as if the text height or line height was changed.

Note that I'm using Kotlin/Anko, so the syntax might look weird compared to regular Java/XML:

```
textView {
    text = someSpannableString
    padding = dip(10)
    isSelectable = true
    typeface = someTypefaceInstance
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
setLineSpacing(0f, 1f)
```

But it did not change anything.

For what it's worth, the particular typeface here is "NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular.otf"

Comment: yea i got this many time ago.. solution is that download same font with other resource and check..problem is in font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with this in xml

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
```

includeFontPadding removes the padding reserved for accents and lineSpacingExtra removes the space between two lines of text.

Hope it helps..

Comment: or some other external library u can use https://github.com/SenhLinsh/NoPaddingTextView

Comment: Marked. BTW don't worry I'm not new. I tried to mark as correct but it told me I had to wait. I don't know when but it seemed they added a 15 minute timer or something. (so I had to do something else to pass time and then I forgot :))